# Properties of Voronoi on Manhattan distance

Tags: geometry, algorithms, voronoi-diagram

There are bunch of information on properties of Voronoi on Euclidean distance, but I cannot find any properties on Voronoi for Manhattan distance. For example in Euclidean Voronoi on average every site has constant number of neighbors. Is it true for Voronoi on l1 norm (Manhattan distance)?